# <button class="next-table entypo-right-dir"></button> <button class="prev-table entypo-left-dir"></button> not working Kindly help me

Tags: javascript

Kindly help me with this issue. Right & previous slide button is not working while showing as mobile & Tab view, can't paste code because of limited characters issues. kindly follow the link below.

http://bighealth.co.in/bookmywellness.html

Regards,
Indradip

Answer (score 1):

Well, now. Looking at your code, of course it won't work -- you specify that it's using jQuery (a la the $ in the first script line), but you never actually load the jQuery library. In the attached code, that's the ONLY thing I've changed. Well, that and working around the body length issue by moving all the CSS to an external file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // The flipping control-center
  // Two functions for every box :(

  // 1
  $(".show-me_1").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip1");
  });
  $(".hide-me_1").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip1");
  });
  // 2
  $(".show-me_2").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip2");
  });
  $(".hide-me_2").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip2");
  });
  // 3
  $(".show-me_3").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip3");
  });
  $(".hide-me_3").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip3");
  });
  // 4
  $(".show-me_4").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip4");
  });
  $(".hide-me_4").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip4");
  });
  // 5
  $(".show-me_5").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip5");
  });
  $(".hide-me_5").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip5");
  });
  // 6
  $(".show-me_6").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip6");
  });
  $(".hide-me_6").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip6");
  });
  // 7
  $(".show-me_7").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip7");
  });
  $(".hide-me_7").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip7");
  });
  // 8
  $(".show-me_8").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip8");
  });
  $(".hide-me_8").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip8");
  });
  // 9
  $(".show-me_9").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").addClass("flip9");
  });
  $(".hide-me_9").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("flip9");
  });

  $('[class*="-me_"]').click(function() {
    var boxclass = $('.box').attr('class');
    $('p.boxclass').html(boxclass);
  });


  // Table Carousel

  $('button.next-table').click(function() {
    var currentone = $('.responsive-tables .active');
    var currenttwo = $('.responsive-tables .activetwo');
    var next = $('.responsive-tables .activetwo + [class*="little"]');
    var last = $('.responsive-tables .last');
    next.addClass('activetwo');
    currentone.removeClass('active').addClass('last');
    currenttwo.removeClass('activetwo').addClass('active');
    last.removeClass('last');

    var echonext = next.attr('class');
    //alert(echonext);


    if (echonext === undefined) {
      $('.little1').addClass('activetwo');
    }

  });

  $('button.prev-table').click(function() {
    var currentone = $('.responsive-tables .active');
    var currenttwo = $('.responsive-tables .activetwo');
    var prev = $('.responsive-tables .last').prev('[class*="little"]');
    var last = $('.responsive-tables .last');
    prev.addClass('last');
    currentone.removeClass('active').addClass('activetwo');
    last.removeClass('last').addClass('active');
    currenttwo.removeClass('activetwo');

    //alert(prev.attr('class'));

    if (prev.attr('class') === undefined) {
      $('.responsive-tables .little9').addClass('last');
    }

  });



}); // .ready-END
```

```html
<link href="https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/css/iconfonts-entypo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/css/price-flip.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="pakete">
  <h1>Responsive Flipping Price-Table</h1>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <p class="section-text">This is a neat price-table. It saves you a lot of space and it looks nice. Have fun! <em>Also try resizing the window, to see the responsive Solution I came up with!</em></p>

  <div class="box">
    <!-- The surrounding box -->

    <!-- The front container -->
    <div class="front">
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <th>...</th>
          <th>Paket 1</th>
          <th>Paket 2</th>
          <th>Paket 3</th>
          <th>Paket 4</th>
          <th>Paket 5</th>
          <th>Paket 6</th>
          <th>Paket 7</th>
          <th>Paket 8</th>
          <th>Paket 9</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 1</th>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 2</th>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 3</th>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 4</th>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 5</th>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 6</th>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service 7</th>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          <td class="entypo-check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Price</th>
          <td>1123,00$</td>
          <td>5813,00$</td>
          <td>2134,00$</td>
          <td>5589,00$</td>
          <td>1442,00$</td>
          <td>3337,00$</td>
          <td>7610,00$</td>
          <td>9871,00$</td>
          <td>5972,00$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>...</th>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_1">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_2">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_3">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_4">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_5">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_6">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_7">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_8">Details</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="show-me_9">Details</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="responsive-tables">
      <div class="little1 active">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>1123,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_1">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little2 activetwo">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>5813,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_2">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little3">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>2134,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_3">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little4">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>5589,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_4">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little5">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 5</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>1442,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_5">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little6">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 6</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>3337,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_6">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little7">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 7</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>7610,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_7">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little8">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 8</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>9871,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_8">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="little9 last">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Paket 9</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 1</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 2</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 3</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 4</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 5</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 6</th>
            <td class="entypo-check"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Service 7</th>
            <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <td>5972,00$</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>
              <button class="show-me_9">Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button class="next-table entypo-right-dir"></button>
      <button class="prev-table entypo-left-dir"></button>

    </div>
    <!-- The backside containers -->
    <div class="back first">
      <h1>Paket 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 1
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_1"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back second">
      <h1>Paket 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Unde, necessitatibus, dicta consequatur quas quis dolores sapiente ducimus incidunt veniam repellat veritatis reiciendis consequuntur corporis tempora harum perspiciatis explicabo perferendis sunt aliquam eius quae consectetur
        eos distinctio ea eaque voluptates mollitia.
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_2"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back third">
      <h1>Paket 3</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 3
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back fourth">
      <h1>Paket 4</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 4
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_4"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back fifth">
      <h1>Paket 5</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 5
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_5"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back sixth">
      <h1>Paket 6</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 5
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_6"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back seventh">
      <h1>Paket 7</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 5
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_7"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back eigth">
      <h1>Paket 8</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 5
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_8"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="back ninth">
      <h1>Paket 9</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto natus labore dicta excepturi ab odit autem dolorem nulla neque sit laudantium sapiente aperiam magni nihil sed cupiditate asperiores at iure.
        <br />
        <br />No. 5
      </p>
      <button class="hide-me_9"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The end of the box -->

</section>
<!-- END of section-wrap -->
```